# Error: Cannot find module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, npm

Firstly, this is not a duplicate. I have searched many questions of SO, but found no answer specifically to installing pagedown. This is my first module. I ran Node.js command prompt as admin, and ran this command.

```
> var pagedown = require("pagedown");
```

Here is the error log:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'pagedown'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at repl:1:16
at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
at repl.js:249:20
at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I am using Windows. Working directory: AppData\Roaming\npm\ <-- empty folder

Comment: And why would defining a variable in the command line install anything? Did you run `npm install pagedown` ?

Comment: I got this message: `pagedown@1.1.0 node_modules\pagedown`

Comment: That you note "admin privileges" makes me wonder about your environment. 1) are you installing the module locally (e.g. `npm install pagedown` note that there is no `-g`. 2) are you running node from within the same working directory? there should be a `node_modules` folder in there. 3) Have you tried any other modules, and do they work? 4) Are you on Mac, Windows, what? My thought is that when you're running something with admin privileges (if this is Windows) that you may be changing your working directory without realizing it.

Comment: I am running on Windows. I right clicked "Node.js Command Prompt" and ran it with "run as Administrator". When i opened it , it shows System32 directory. I have folder in AppData\Roaming\ named `npm`, it is empty.

Comment: @milkandtang
1. On installing `npm install pagedown` i got this message: `pagedown@1.1.0 node_modules\pagedown` in command prompt.
2. I have no such folder named `node_modules`.
3. This is my first module.
4. Windows

Answer (score 1):

**Sure that npm is installed**

Go to command line (Windows_button+R), write "cmd", press Enter
Go to your_app_folder by command line
Just write "*npm install pagedown*", then press Enter